# How to send ResourceId from Fragment to another class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am implementing custom keyboard in my fragment. I want to send ResourceId of EditText located in my fragment's UI to custom keyboard class. I am getting NullPointerException on receiving ResourceId in custom keyboard class which means Resourceid is not sent.

The code I've implemented is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_barcode_detail,
            container, false);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
editText_barcode = (EditText) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.editText_barcode);
mCustomKeyboard = new CustomKeyboard(mActivity, R.id.keyboardview,R.xml.hexkbd);
    System.out.println("====inac====" + R.id.editText_barcode);
    mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(mActivity, R.id.editText_barcode);

    return rootView;
}
```

Custom keyboard Class is:

```
class CustomKeyboard {


private KeyboardView mKeyboardView;
/** A link to the activity that hosts the {@link #mKeyboardView}. */
private Activity mHostActivity;
private  EditText edittext;


public CustomKeyboard(Activity host, int viewid, int layoutid) {
    mHostActivity= host;
    mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid); //   
Getting Resourceid successfully 
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));
    mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); 
    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);

 }

public void registerEditText( int resid) {
    // Find the EditText 'resid'
    System.out.println("======ed"+resid);
     edittext= (EditText)mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);//   
Not Getting Resourceid 
}
```

Comment: Instead 'R.id.editText_barcode' send 'editText_barcode ' object EditText

Comment: just accept my answer....

Answer (score 0):

Instead 'R.id.editText_barcode' 
send 'editText_barcode ' object EditText